# Filtering out values in a column that are zero

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have the following dataset:

```
071,36,035,08422,46217,00000,1,A,Broadalbin village (pt.),New York,18,46,46,46,45,45,44,46,44,46,43,43
071,36,045,29322,56209,00000,1,A,Glen Park village (pt.),New York,42,42,42,42,43,42,44,43,42,42,41,40
162,36,000,64881,00000,00000,0,A,Saltaire village,New York,37,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41
157,36,103,64881,00000,00000,0,A,Saltaire village,New York,37,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41
071,36,103,64881,38000,00000,1,A,Saltaire village,New York,37,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41
061,36,013,00000,13035,00000,1,F,Cattaraugus Reservation,New York,38,38,38,38,37,37,39,39,38,38,38,40
061,36,029,00000,75011,00000,1,F,Tonawanda Reservation,New York,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,37,37,37,37,36
061,36,009,00000,60950,00000,1,A,Red House town,New York,38,33,33,33,34,34,35,35,34,34,35,35
071,36,065,61115,75280,00000,1,A,Remsen village (pt.),New York,28,28,28,28,28,30,28,27,27,29,29,29
071,36,023,35276,18421,00000,1,A,Homer village (pt.),New York,31,31,31,31,31,30,30,30,30,29,29,29
071,36,099,55816,63440,00000,1,A,Ovid village (pt.),New York,19,27,27,27,27,29,29,26,26,26,26,25
071,36,059,22260,56000,00000,1,A,East Hills village (pt.),New York,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23
071,36,059,47636,34000,00000,1,A,Mineola village (pt.),New York,16,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22
071,36,043,37275,27199,00000,1,A,Ilion village (pt.),New York,22,23,23,23,23,23,22,22,22,22,22,22
071,36,029,82084,15011,00000,1,A,Williamsville village (pt.),New York,18,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13
162,36,000,20379,00000,00000,0,A,Dering Harbor village,New York,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11
157,36,103,20379,00000,00000,0,A,Dering Harbor village,New York,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11
071,36,103,20379,66839,00000,1,A,Dering Harbor village,New York,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11
071,36,071,26319,29553,00000,1,A,Florida village (pt.),New York,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
071,36,099,78553,66333,00000,1,A,Waterloo village (pt.),New York,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
071,36,057,26924,12122,00000,1,A,Fort Plain village (pt.),New York,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
071,36,053,31709,23305,00000,1,A,Hamilton village (pt.),New York,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
061,36,003,00000,54523,00000,1,F,Oil Springs Reservation,New York,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
157,36,099,28640,00000,00000,0,A,Geneva city (pt.),New York,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
071,36,099,28640,28640,00000,1,A,Geneva city (pt.),New York,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
071,36,089,46019,51330,00000,1,A,Massena village (pt.),New York,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
071,36,071,15297,29553,00000,1,A,Chester village (pt.),New York,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
071,36,059,28178,53000,00000,1,A,Garden City village (pt.),New York,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
071,36,053,31709,44435,00000,1,A,Hamilton village (pt.),New York,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
071,36,051,19664,70101,00000,1,A,Dansville village (pt.),New York,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
071,36,039,36167,38638,00000,1,A,Hunter village (pt.),New York,A,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
071,36,037,18201,19719,00000,1,A,Corfu village (pt.),New York,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
061,36,099,00000,28640,00000,0,F,Geneva city,New York,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
061,36,063,00000,75011,00000,1,F,Tonawanda Reservation,New York,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
061,36,013,00000,14072,00000,1,S,Chautauqua Lake UT,New York,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
061,36,009,00000,54523,00000,1,F,Oil Springs Reservation,New York,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

And I want to print out the 10 lines with the smallest number in the last column that isn't zero, so this:

```
071,36,043,37275,27199,00000,1,A,Ilion village (pt.),New York,22,23,23,23,23,23,22,22,22,22,22,22
071,36,029,82084,15011,00000,1,A,Williamsville village (pt.),New York,18,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13
162,36,000,20379,00000,00000,0,A,Dering Harbor village,New York,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11
157,36,103,20379,00000,00000,0,A,Dering Harbor village,New York,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11
071,36,103,20379,66839,00000,1,A,Dering Harbor village,New York,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11
071,36,071,26319,29553,00000,1,A,Florida village (pt.),New York,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
071,36,099,78553,66333,00000,1,A,Waterloo village (pt.),New York,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
071,36,057,26924,12122,00000,1,A,Fort Plain village (pt.),New York,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
071,36,053,31709,23305,00000,1,A,Hamilton village (pt.),New York,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
061,36,003,00000,54523,00000,1,F,Oil Springs Reservation,New York,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

The command I used to get this far was:

```
cat [filename] | grep 'New York' | sort -n -r -t, -k20
```

But I'm not sure how to do the rest, which I'm sure I'll need grep for

Comment: You want to filter out lines where the 10th field is new york correct?

Comment: yeah, what I have already just missing the last command. I don't know how to filter out lines that contain 0 in the last column

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, '$10 == "New York" && $NF > 0' input | sort -t, -rnk22 | tail -10
```

The awk will print only lines where the 10th column equals `New York` and the last column is greater than 0.

sort will reverse sort on column 22 numerically.

tail -10 will print only the last 10 lines.

Comment: This output prints the ones ending in zero on my screen

Comment: @Mathew what if you change `$NF` to `$22`?  And/or are you sure your input is exactly what you have pasted here?

Comment: Yeah still wouldn't work, found the issue. There was a carriage return in there I didn't account for, the correct commands would be: cat [filename] | grep 'New York' | sort -n -r -t, -k20 | grep -P ',0^M$' -v | tail -n 10. Note ^M here is 'ctrl v ctrl m'

Comment: I mean that may work but being the "correct" command is debatable.  More correct would be `mac2unix  input; awk -F, '$10 == "New York" && $NF > 0' input | sort -t, -rnk22 | tail -10`

Comment: agreed, there is no 'correct' here

Comment: Mathew the command [you suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758320/filtering-out-values-in-a-column-that-are-zero#comment1445056_758322) would be incorrect though as it has a UUOC, unnecessarily uses the non-portable `-P` with grep, is sorting on the wrong field (20 vs 22), and is partial-regexp matching on New York anywhere on the line (so it'd falsely match on a town named `Little New Yorkshire` in state `Pennsylvania`) instead of full-field string matching just on the apparent state field.

Comment: @jesse_b if you add `{sub(/\r$/,"")}` as the first thing in your awk command then you don't need to call `mac2unix  input` (which would make your answer non-portable) before calling awk.

Comment: @jesse_b `tail` is fine because 10 is the default `n` value.

Comment: @EdMorton true, I think the non unix line endings aren't strictly relevant to the question though especially since it hasn't been edited into the question.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh yes but it's usually better to be explicit where possible, especially in this case where a new user may just be saying "10" to represent "n lines" much easier for them to change the number when it's explicitly specified.

Comment: @jess_b my concern, beyond what might happen if any further awk enhancements are needed, is that idk what `sort -n` will do with non-numeric values such as `0\r` and `1\r` would be - maybe it'll drop the `\r`s and make the comparison numeric, or maybe it'll ignore the `-n`s and make the comparison alphabetic (in which case `2\r` would be a higher value than `12\r`), I just don't know. I do know how it'd behave with numbers and that we really do want numeric comparisons so IMO it's best to just discard the `\r`s,

Comment: @EdMorton for sure it is but this question isn't about how to remove bad line endings.   That would be a separate question that should be addressed before the parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N filter '$10 == "New York" && $22 > 0' then sort -nr 22 then tail file
```

---

Using `gawk`:

```bash
$ awk -F, -v var=10 
'$10 == "New York" && $NF > 0 {ar[$0]=$NF}
END{asorti(ar, b, "@val_num_asc"); 
for(i=var;i>=1;i--)print b[i]}' file
```

---

```bash
$ csvsql -I -H  --query 'SELECT * FROM file WHERE j == "New York" AND v > 0 ORDER BY CAST(v AS INTEGER) DESC' file | tail
```

`-H` is used because of header less file. This creates default headers (a,b,c..).

```bash
$ csvsql -I -H --query 'SELECT * FROM file WHERE j == "New York" AND v > 0 ORDER BY CAST(v AS INTEGER) DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET ( SELECT count(*) FROM file WHERE j == "New York" AND v > 0 ) - 10' file | csvformat -K1
```